# Error when trying to find if a value exists in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to using SQLite databases and android mobile development. I am trying to check if the username entered by a edit text field exists in the database. When I run it and click a button, the application crashes. This is my code.

```
 public boolean findUsername(String username) {
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_L, new String[] {
        KEY_USERID, KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASSWORD,KEY_SECRETQ,KEY_ANSWER}, KEY_USERNAME + "="
        + username, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
      return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
}
```

The error from the log cat states that:

```
no such column: bobby: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT userId, username, password,    secretQ, answer FROM Login WHERE username=bobby
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should form your query like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT userId, username, password,    secretQ, answer FROM Login WHERE username='bobby'
```

You have to put quotes to username.

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_L, new String[] {
        KEY_USERID, KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASSWORD,KEY_SECRETQ,KEY_ANSWER}, KEY_USERNAME + "='"
        + username +"'", null, null, null, null, null);
```

Try above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works fine now :) One more question, do i have to always specify all the column names in the table like this :   ourDatabase.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_L, new String[] {
        KEY_USERID, KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASSWORD,KEY_SECRETQ,KEY_ANSWER}

Comment: @Sindu_ No, It is not necessary , You can specify single column also. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_L, new String[] {
        KEY_USERID, KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASSWORD,KEY_SECRETQ,KEY_ANSWER}, KEY_USERNAME + "=?",
        username, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
Cursor C = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE_L, new String[] {
        KEY_USERID}, KEY_USERNAME + "= ?" , new String[] {username}, null, null,null);
```